# JApplet instance

Tags: java, applet

How can I get in a java class an instance from a class extends from jApplet 
Thanks.
this is a shortcut of class

```
public class Hangman
        extends java.applet.Applet
        implements Runnable, MouseListener, KeyListener {

    /* This is the maximum number of incorrect guesses. */
    final int maxTries = 5;
    /* This is the maximum length of a secret word. */
    final int maxWordLen = 20;
    /* This buffer holds the letters in the secret word. */
    char secretWord[];
    /* This is the length of the secret word. */
    int secretWordLen;
    /* This buffer holds the letters which the user typed
    but don't appear in the secret word. */
    char wrongLetters[];
    /* This is the current number of incorrect guesses. */
    int wrongLettersCount;
    /* This buffer holds letters that the user has successfully
    guessed. */
    char word[];
    /* Number of correct 
....
}
```

Comment: As an aside, this is a applet, not a JApplet.

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Comment: i expect he has some other class that he wants to be able to call methods on the Hangman class of the existing instance.

Comment: please try to rewrite your question once more as to avoid any misunderstandings and unable us swift and correct answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate an applet like any other class, with the constructor. For this class to be usable as an applet, it should have a no-argument constructor, so you can simply write

```
Hangman h = new Hangman();
```

But for your applet to properly work, you probably need to put it into an applet container, or emulate such.